# How to prevent a jQuery widget appended to a selectable from growing bigger onmouseover?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, onmouseover, mousehover, jquery-widgets

**TLDR UPDATE:** here a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/afarber/dL7t309v/1/) demonstrating my problem.

In an HTML game I have created [a custom jQuery widget](https://raspasy.de/raspasy/Table.js) called `table` representing a rectangle green table with up to 4 players sitting at it:

[image: screenshot 1]

In the above screenshot 4 such tables are appended to a `#tablesList` selectable by the following code:

```
var tablesList = $('#selectable').selectable();

var table1 = $('<li/>').appendTo(tablesList).table({ gid: 3 });
var table2 = $('<li/>').appendTo(tablesList).table({
    gid: 104,
    player0: {
        rep: Math.random(),
        photo: 'http://afarber.de/images/farber.jpg'
    }
});
var table3 = $('<li/>').appendTo(tablesList).table({
    gid: 115,
    player0: {
        rep: Math.random()
    },
    player1: {
    },
    player2: {
        rep: Math.random(),
        photo: 'https://raspasy.de/raspasy/images/male_sad.png'
    },
    player3: {
        rep: Math.random(),
        photo: 'https://raspasy.de/raspasy/images/female_happy.png'
    }
});
var table4 = $('<li/>').appendTo(tablesList).table({
    gid: 115,
    player0: {
        photo: 'https://raspasy.de/raspasy/images/female_happy.png'
    },
    player1: {
        rep: Math.random(),
        photo: 'https://raspasy.de/raspasy/images/female_sad.png'
    },
    player2: {
        rep: Math.random(),
        photo: 'https://raspasy.de/raspasy/images/male_sad.png'
    },
    player3: {
        rep: Math.random(),
        photo: 'https://raspasy.de/raspasy/images/female_happy.png'
    }
});
```

The `#tablesList` has the CSS property `overflow-y:` set to `scroll`:

```
#selectable .ui-selecting { background: #FECA40; }
#selectable .ui-selected  { background: #F39814; color: white; }
#selectable { 
    list-style-type:    none; 
    margin:             0;
    padding:            0;
    height:             500px;
    overflow-y:         scroll;
}
```

My problem is: when I hover the mouse pointer over one of the `table` widgets, then it seems to change into some CSS state with slightly bigger dimensions and thus pushes the right tables to the next row in the `#tablesList`:

**Screenshot 1** (the mouse is over the second table):

[image: screenshot 2]

**Screenshot 2** (the mouse is over the third table):

[image: screenshot 3]

As you can see, the fourth table is always pushed down. And if I move the mouse pointer away, this creates an annoying flickering effect, where the 4th table changes between the 1st and 2nd rows.

My question is how to prevent this please? I have tried inspecting CSS in the browser dev. tools but failed to spot any related CSS property.

My CSS file [style.css](https://raspasy.de/wp-content/themes/twentytwenty-child/style.css) is listed below and you can see the effect by visiting [the game web page](https://raspasy.de/ws/google) (behind Google OAuth though, sorry for that):

```
#selectable .ui-selecting { background: #FECA40; }
#selectable .ui-selected  { background: #F39814; color: white; }
#selectable { 
    list-style-type:    none; 
    margin:             0;
    padding:            0;
    height:             500px;
    overflow-y:         scroll;
}

body {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

fieldset {
    border: 0px;
}

.ui-draggable, 
.ui-droppable {
    background-position: top;
}

#gameDiv {
    position: relative;
}

#gameCanvas {
    background: radial-gradient(#FFFFFF, #99CC99);
}

:-webkit-full-screen,
:-moz-full-screen,
:-ms-fullscreen,
:fullscreen {
    background: #FFF;
}

#lobbyTable {
    background: #FFF;
}

#kukuSlider {
    width:          300px;
    margin:         15px;
}

#red, #green, #blue {
    width:          300px;
    margin:         15px;
}

#swatch {
    padding:        10px;
    margin:         5px;
    color:          #FFF;
}

#red   .ui-slider-range  { background:   #ef2929; }
#red   .ui-slider-handle { border-color: #ef2929; }
#green .ui-slider-range  { background:   #8ae234; }
#green .ui-slider-handle { border-color: #8ae234; }
#blue  .ui-slider-range  { background:   #729fcf; }
#blue  .ui-slider-handle { border-color: #729fcf; }

.raspasy-player {
    position:           relative;
    background:         #FFF no-repeat center;
    background-size:    contain;
    box-shadow: 0 0 32px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    width:              160px;
    height:             120px;
}

.raspasy-player-name {
    position:           absolute;
    font-size:          18px;
    background:         #FFF;
    color:              #000;
    text-align:         left;
    left:               0;
    bottom:             0;
    padding:            2px;
    width:              156px;
    height:             20px;
}

.raspasy-player-bid {
    position:           absolute;
    font-size:          18px;
    background:         #FFF;
    color:              #000;
    text-align:         right;
    right:              0;
    top:                0;
    padding:            2px;
    width:              36px;
    height:             20px;
}

.raspasy-player-trix {
    position:           absolute;
    font-size:          18px;
    background:         #FFF;
    color:              #000;
    text-align:         right;
    right:              0;
    bottom:             0;
    padding:            2px;
    width:              36px;
    height:             20px;
}

.raspasy-player-rep {
    position:           absolute;
    right:              0;
    bottom:             0;
}

.raspasy-player-bad-big {
    position:           relative;
    background:         #C00;
    width:              50px;
    height:             1px;
    display:            none;
}

.raspasy-player-bad-small {
    position:           relative;
    background:         #C00;
    width:              25px;
    height:             1px;
    display:            none;
}

.raspasy-player-good-big {
    position:           relative;
    background:         #6C6;
    width:              50px;
    height:             1px;
    display:            none;
}

.raspasy-player-good-small {
    position:           relative;
    background:         #6C6;
    width:              25px;
    height:             1px;
    display:            none;
}

.raspasy-table {
    position:           relative;
    background:         #A3DD8E;
    color:              white;
    margin:             50px; 
    float:              left; 
    border:             4px solid #91BCE5;
    border-radius:      16px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 32px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    width:              160px; 
    height:             160px; 
}

.raspasy-table-gid {
    position:           absolute;
    font-size:          1.5em; 
    top:                65px;
    width:              100%;
    color:              white;
    text-align:         center; 
}

.raspasy-table-player0 {
    position:           absolute;
    left:               -40px;
    top:                50px;
    background:         #FFF no-repeat center;
    background-size:    contain;
    box-shadow: 0 0 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    width:              80px;
    height:             60px;
    display:            none;
}

.raspasy-table-player1 {
    position:           absolute;
    left:               40px;
    top:                -30px;
    background:         #FFF no-repeat center;
    background-size:    contain;
    box-shadow: 0 0 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    width:              80px;
    height:             60px;
    display:            none;
}

.raspasy-table-player2 {
    position:           absolute;
    left:               120px;
    top:                50px;
    background:         #FFF no-repeat center;
    background-size:    contain;
    box-shadow: 0 0 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    width:              80px;
    height:             60px;
    display:            none;
}

.raspasy-table-player3 {
    position:           absolute;
    left:               40px;
    top:                130px;
    background:         #FFF no-repeat center;
    background-size:    contain;
    box-shadow: 0 0 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    width:              80px;
    height:             60px;
    display:            none;
}
```

I have also asked my question at the [jQuery UI forum](https://forum.jquery.com/topic/how-to-prevent-a-jquery-widget-appended-to-a-selectable-from-growing-bigger-onmouseover).

Comment: Could you show us the code of your `table` plugin or at least the resulting markup so that we have an example to reproduce?

Comment: Yes, it is in the very 1st sentence of my question. You probably have not noticed it :-)

Comment: Do you got your answer? Because I can't use your `table` function because of the error "Uncaught TypeError: $(...).appendTo(...).table is not a function". You can see it on the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vdnp9ay6/)

Comment: Here I have fixed your fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/afarber/dL7t309v/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last `table` jumps when you hover on the 3rd one because you give it the class `ui-state-hover` which changes the border from `4px` to `1px`, thus subtracting from the `height` and `width` of the table. This problem is easily solved by adding `box-sizing: border-box` to the `raspasy-table` elements. That way the border will appear inwards, instead of outwards.

Comment: Thank you Vlad (upvoted your response), but unfortunately your CSS trick does not quite work for me (tried with Edge): https://jsfiddle.net/afarber/dL7t309v/6/

Comment: You added `box-sizing: content-box` instead of `box-sizing: border-box`. Try again. I'm using Edge also and it works if you give `raspasy-table` the property of `box-sizing: border-box`.

Comment: Thank you Vlad and sorry for my mistake. Do you happen to know how to set the onmouseover color for the `raspasy-table` (currently it is light grey), what would be the jQuery UI CSS for that? Also I have understood that the root cause for the onmouseover behaviour is `this._hoverable(this.element);` called by my custom jQuery Widget, but I would like to keep that line

Comment: Just to be clear - you want to change the `raspasy-table` background color? If so just add this rule in your css stylesheet.

`.raspasy-table.ui-state-hover{ background-color: COLOR }`

Comment: Yes, but only in onmouseover state. Doesn't jQuery UI have some predefined CSS class for that?

Comment: So you would like to change the background color using jQuery instead of CSS?

Comment: Maybe I will ask a separate question, with more details, thank you Vlad! Have a nice day

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218203/discussion-between-vlad-solomon-and-alexander-farber).